# Pyramid chart with highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Have managed to get a pyramid chart like bellow, but as the percentage data will vary, the pyramid shape will get distorted. I need to maintain the pyramid shape even if percentage data is varying. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WpFzv/2/) Thanks in advance

[image: pyramid chart]

Code:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'area'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Pyramid Chart'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11'],
            tickmarkPlacement: 'off',
            title: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Percentage'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value;
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' millions'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                lineColor: '#666666',
                lineWidth: 1,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'A',
            zInxed:555555,
            data: [null,null,null,null,80,100,80,null,null,null,null]
            },
            {
            name: 'B',
            zInxed:666666,
            data: [null,null,null,60,80,80,80,60,null,null,null]
            },
            {
            name: 'C',
            zInxed:777777,
            data: [null,null,40,60,60,60,60,60,40,null,null]
            },
            {
            name: 'D',
            zInxed:888888,
            data: [null,20,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,20,null]
            },
            {
            name: 'E',
            zInxed:999999,
            data: [0,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,0]
        }]
    });
```

Comment: Could you show that distorted pyramid?

Comment: @PawełFus: pls check this http://jsfiddle.net/WpFzv/3/

Comment: I think you need to recalculate x-position for points in that way, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/WpFzv/5/

Comment: @PawełFus thanks for the time and efforts. the data could vary in any direction as in http://jsfiddle.net/WpFzv/6/ Is there a way by which I could generalize this solution to have the pyramid shape intact

Comment: My example was only to show how you should change x-value for points, it wasn't solution for all cases :)  You need to write your own function which will calculate x-value and display proper pyramide.

Comment: Yep thanks for the help, I am thinking about keeping y-axis interval at min value and then adjusting all the series to keep pyramid shape intact

Comment: what a confounding way to display data, though!